# fail to set html element style to transparent

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to inherit the background of breadcrumbs element from the father div through its CSS configuration but I fail.
I was trying to set its CSS to background: transparent or inherit but it fails.

here is a link where this issue happens - the breadcrumbs has grey background while I want it to be white as the reset of the page.
Link to the problematic page: http://doitonlinediy.com/?s=page

Any thoughts/idea why I fail to set it ?

Comment: Add `#et-main-area { background-color: #fff; }`

Comment: @Muhammad Usman - thanks but to set it to a fixed white color I know how to do. I am looking for a method to inherit the background color from the father div

Comment: Or just `p#breadcrumb {background-color: #fff;}`

Answer (score 0):

The background color is displayed is set into the body's css

```
#body {
    background-color: #e1dedf;
}
```

Remove it or replace it and set the background color on your breadcrumb only

Answer (score 0):

while strolling on your website sample I found out that whenever you set your breadcrumb background color to inherit parent's background style it always gives you the `grey` color. That's because of your `body` css background.

```
body.custom-background {
    background-color: #e1dedf;
}
```

Try to change the background and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the

```
body.custom-background
```

Answer (score 0):

u can do something transparent by using RGBa, Like this..
h1 {color: rgba(123, 88, 9, 0.5);}
the value(123, 88, 9) are using for color, and the value (0.5) is using for transfarent..